# Get the latest messages only from MySQL using jQuery (Ajax) and PHP ? (Live Chat APP)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I'm trying to figure out how I can fetch the latest (newest) messages from MySQL that has not already been fetched.

**What I want:**
If user A sends a message, I would like user B to fetch that message, but only once.
I don't want to fetch everything, as this would be bad in the long run.

My current solution kinda works but the problem is that it **sometimes fetches the same message** twice and another problem is that **if a client where to get a lagspike, he would miss those messages because the current solution is based upon a timeframe**.

**What I currently got:**

jQuery (Ajax)

```
setInterval(function () {
console.log('Attempting to update');
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "palenc.php?hb=<?php echo $hb; ?>",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
     if (data == 2) {
       console.log('No messages to fetch');
     } else {
     var password = "<?php echo $key; ?>";
     for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
       var from = data[i][0];
       var emsg = data[i][1];
       var pmsg = decrypt(emsg, password);
       var msg = pmsg.toString(PalieEncryption.enc.Utf8);
       $("#chat").append('<div class="left spotmsg"><div class="chat-
       avatar pull-left"><img src="https://example.net/img/them.png" 
       alt="avatar" width="48" height="48"></div><div class="message">
       <div class="arrow-left"></div><p><strong>@'+from+'</strong></p>
       <p 
       class="txt">'+msg+'</p></div></div>');
     }
     $('textarea').focus();
     $(".chat_area").animate({ scrollTop: $(".chat_area")
     [0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
     }
     }
     });
     }, 1350);
```

PHP

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT chat_user, chat_msg FROM chat_msg 
WHERE chat_id = ? AND chat_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 SECOND) AND 
chat_user != ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $id,$_SESSION['sess_user']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_all()) {
header('Content-Type: application/json');
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Comment: You could add an extra column with a boolean flag and `UPDATE`'ing that column. About your *"sometimes fetches the same message twice"*, you can use DISTINCT / GROUP BY.

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example? MySQL is not my strong side

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an autoincrementing primary key on the messages table, why not send the primary key along with the message to the client?  Then when the client requests newer messages, it can send back the primary key of the most recent message received, and the server can query for all messages for that user with a primary key greater than the one returned.

Comment: Good idea! That should work but how can I pass the last ID to PHP from jQuery without using cookies or sessions?

Comment: O_o wait, since the client is not reloading the page, I could just store it inside a VAR right?

Comment: @Persson The client initiates requests for new messages, right?  Then include the latest message id in the GET request.  When the client requests new messages, use the $.ajax data option to pass the last_message_id as a GET parameter.  Then read it in PHP using the $_GET associative array.